# show thumbnails in file chooser dialog

Tags: filemanager, thumbnails

is there any way to show thumbnails in file chooser dialog in ubuntu or in any other distro ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to scroll with your mouse while pressing the CTRL key down?

Comment: As I see here the same question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408841/no-image-preview-when-file-selected-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are hitting a sensitive issue: the [infamous GTK file picker bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141154&). It was opened in 2004, and has been closed in 2018 to be moved to the new Gnome GitLab bugtracking platform. [There](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/233), the bug happily lives on up to this day.

> is there any way to show thumbnails in file chooser dialog in ubuntu
> or in any other distro ?

Yes, for sure...

...however not on a GTK based desktop. Users of a QT based desktop such as KDE Plasma have more luck: Their file picker has a well functioning thumbnail view.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply     
i've been searching for ages with no luck. now i understand

Comment: Latest update from emmanuele bassi (maintainer): "So, let's try and outline something that people can work on: port the file system model used by GtkFileChooserWidget from GtkTreeModel to GListModel, using the various models available in GTK4. Use GtkColumnView to implement the list views for the various states of the file chooser widget (browse, recent, search). Add a GtkGridView for an "icon-browse" state. Each one of these steps comes with various sub-issues that may require additional API or, at least, some poking at the internals of GTK...

Comment: ... The GTK developers are happy to offer guidance; join the #gtk IRC channel (bridged on Matrix as #gtk:gnome.org)."

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this 18 year old bug will finally be dying soon: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/yab9ux/gtk_file_picker_meme_is_finally_dead_after_18/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2z-v3v6vwk

https://wiki.installgentoo.com/wiki/File_Picker_meme

> In late April, 2004, a bug was submitted to GNOME's bugzilla[1], suggesting a feature to add to the GtkFileChooser, the main tool for picking files (to upload, open, etc.) within a Gnome Desktop a thumbnail view similar to that found on Windows.

Can't wait to see this released.