# Icon view in google chrome file chooser is gone on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

Google Chrome's file chooser has preview in previous versions of Ubuntu(21.10 and earlier).

It is painful since I can't see which one is the correct picture when uploading in browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I had an image preview in the previous LTS release and it's still there after the upgrade.

Comment: There's a solution for Firefox under about:config, according to https://askubuntu.com/a/1428041/286078

Is there anything equivalent under chrome://about?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No progress on this front. Rather a regression with GTK4.

Indeed, Google Chrome is using the latest GTK4 (libadwaita) file dialog on Ubuntu 22.04. An icon view in GTK dialogs has been [lacking forever](https://askubuntu.com/a/1325496/558158). While GTK3 dialogs were at least still able to show a preview of the currently selected file, that possibility does not appear to be implemented (currently?) in GTK4 file picker dialogs.

Comment: is there any related issues to track?