# Recover image preview in file explorer in Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, filesystem, 22.04, previews

Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and have tried for days to recover image preview when searching thru files.

Thus far all help links for this problem tell you to access "preferences" and go to "performance" and change settings that no longer exist.

Can someone please explain how to fix this without referring to previous versions of Ubuntu settings with "performance" settings that no longer exist? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify. I have no idea what this is about, what you tried, what you expect to happen but what happens instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Icon view in google chrome file chooser is gone on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406730/icon-view-in-google-chrome-file-chooser-is-gone-on-ubuntu-22-04)