# How to change ubuntu 22.04 open file dialog from list view to grid view?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

In ubuntu 20.04 it had grid option in open file window. i could preview pictures before selecting but after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 i see no option to change it to grid view. i tried to find options but all tutorial are related to workspace grid options :(

[image: open file dialog in ubuntu 22.04]

Comment: Unfortunately, [this isn't something you can control](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406737/1222991) in 22.04. Hopefully the people behind Gnome will restore the functionality in the near future 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Icon view in google chrome file chooser is gone on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406730/icon-view-in-google-chrome-file-chooser-is-gone-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Pathetic limitation. Not even a preview. How are you supposed to pic an image, a photo, an icon?