# No image preview when file selected ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, previews

I was using Ubuntu 20.04, when uploading Images in chrome i could see the image preview of the selected File.

Now in ubuntu 22.04 I can't see the image preview.
[image: I want to see the image preview in this file open dialog]

I tried:

- installed Gnome sushi
- List item preferences / performance  show thumbnails

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Icon view in google chrome file chooser is gone on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406730/icon-view-in-google-chrome-file-chooser-is-gone-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: no it dose not   answer my question

Comment: Yes it does. It does not solve your problem, but it does answer your question.

Comment: have the same issue. So annoying. gnome is silly

Comment: As I see here the same question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325380/show-thumbnails-in-file-chooser-dialog/1325496

Comment: I have this issue for example in Slack or Signal, where I upload many pictures (screenshots) every day, now I cannot see which image I am uploading. Does anyone have a fix for that? Using Ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround you may use GMOME Sushi, which you can install by running in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-sushi
```

After installing Sushi, select a file and hit the space bar. A window opens to show the file, then hit up or down arrow, browsing the files, immediately showing them. Also see this screenshot:

[image: GNOME Sushi in action]

Comment: Apparently, you didn't get the question properly. Your picture shows the file browser, the question is about the file picker (open files window).

Comment: I think I do, but the solution I found is not like having a preview inside the Window. But it's better than nothing.

Comment: the ubuntu doc link  -> https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-preview.html.en