# On Ubuntu 22.10 I cannot see which images I am uploading for example using Slack or Signal

Tags: 22.10

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to **22.10** and now when I need to upload images to programs like Slack or Signal or a browser, **I cannot see** the image preview anymore.

I take many screenshots per day that I need to send, and now it's hard to see which image is the correct one.

*See screenshot:*

[image: upload file dialog]

This is the process id of the file picker:

`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "xdg-desktop-portal-gnome", "xdg-desktop-portal-gnome"`

Does anyone have a fix for this?

I am using the i3 window manager, but that has not been an issue before.
Is there a utility that I can install, so I can see image previews?

Related links (without a solution):

- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/43
- [No image preview when file selected ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408841/no-image-preview-when-file-selected-ubuntu-22-04)

**EDIT:**

Before this update, I was able to see a bigger image in the **sidebar** if I clicked on a image.
Why is the sidebar gone? Can I add it somehow with another package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [22.04: Image Preview in File Selector menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431852/22-04-image-preview-in-file-selector-menu)

Comment: What is the solution? What can I do so I can preview the pictures I am uploading?

Comment: Also if it was not clear, in Ubuntu 20.04 this worked perfectly, I could see a bigger image in the **sidebar**

Comment: @viktorsmari solution is to wait until the developers add the ability to see thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

See this [video of Brodie Robertson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bxlf9v-SWW4). After 18 years, it appears that, finally, GTK is soon going to have a file picker that can show thumbnails.